# How do you set up selenium grid using docker on windows?

Tags: selenium, docker, protractor

Steps I have taken already
1. Downloaded and installed Docker Toolbox for windows
2. Open Docker Quickstart terminal
3. Entered the below commands to pull the docker images from dockerhub and run them
`docker pull selenium/hub`
`docker pull selenium/node-chrome`
`docker pull selenium/node-firefox`
`docker run -d -P \--name hub selenium/hub`
`docker run -d --link hub:hub -P \--name chrome selenium/node-chrome`
`docker run -d --link hub:hub -P \--name firefox selenium/node-firefox`

It appears to be running when I type `docker logs hub` but I am unable to route my tests to the hub's address on the virtualbox VM using `seleniumAddress` in my conf.js file  or see it using http://ipAddress:4444/grid/console .

Ideally I would like to use this set up to expand the amount of parallel test instances I can run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately the selenium docker image might be [broken since 4 days ago](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/208) but you can try my [alternative one](https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium#run):

1. Pull the image and run as many containers as you need

   ```
   docker pull elgalu/selenium

   docker run -d --name=grid4 -p 4444:24444 -p 5904:25900 \
       -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm -e VNC_PASSWORD=hola elgalu/selenium

   docker run -d --name=grid5 -p 4445:24444 -p 5905:25900 \
       -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm -e VNC_PASSWORD=hola elgalu/selenium

   docker run -d --name=grid6 -p 4446:24444 -p 5906:25900 \
       -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm -e VNC_PASSWORD=hola elgalu/selenium
   ```
2. Wait until the all the grids started properly before starting the tests *(Optional but recommended)*

   ```
   docker exec grid4 wait_all_done 30s
   docker exec grid5 wait_all_done 30s
   docker exec grid6 wait_all_done 30s
   ```

After this, Selenium should be up and running at `http://localhost:4444/wd/hub`. Open the url in your browser to confirm it is running.
If you are using Mac (OSX) or [Microsoft Windows](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/windows/) `localhost` won't work! Find out the correct IP through `boot2docker ip` or `docker-machine ip default`.

So set the selenium port accordingly for each of your test:

- 1st test should connect to `http://ipAddress:4444/wd/hub`
- 2nd test to `http://ipAddress:4445/wd/hub`
- 3rd test to `http://ipAddress:4446/wd/hub`

You can run as many as your hardware can take.

Comment: This worked great, one issue I may have had with the previous attempt was I was using the IP address derived from docker logs <container> instead of my docker-machine ip. I am going to use this for now and maybe migrate back over to the normal selenium docker image in a few days. Once more thank you for the explanation.

Comment: This should be fixed now according to this issue: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/208

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [Protractor Cookbook w/ Docker](https://github.com/angular/protractor-cookbook/tree/master/protractor-docker). The instructions are listed step-by-step using selenium-grid and docker compose. Docker-selenium [issue #208](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/208) has been fixed.

So you'll need to pull down the latest images*:

```
docker pull selenium/hub:latest
docker pull selenium/node-chrome-debug:latest
```

Start the selenium grid:

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --name selenium-hub selenium/hub:latest
```

Then add selenium nodes. I like to use the chrome-debug and firefox-debug versions to VNC to watch the tests.

```
docker run -d -p <port>:5900 --link selenium-hub:hub selenium/node-chrome-debug:latest
```

After linking your selenium grid, this should be enough to run your Protractor test using the `seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'`.

For debugging, find the VNC port for the container with:

```
docker port <container-name or container-id> 5900
```

and access it via VNC Viewer.

**Note:**

- At the time of this writing, 'latest' appears to be tied to a ~2.53.1 version of selenium server. As of Protractor 4.0.11 (the latest version of Protractor), this is the supported version that should be used. Note that the instructions on the [Selenium-docker GitHub](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium) appear to be for tailored for selenium server 3.0.1.

Answer (score -1):

You can use below compose file to setup grid and access via VNC

**# To execute this docker-compose yml file use docker-compose -f  up

**# Add the "-d" flag at the end for deattached execution****

```
version: '2'
services:
  firefoxnode:
    image: selenium/node-firefox-debug
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      HUB_HOST: hub
    ports:
      - "32772:5900"

  chromenode:
    image: selenium/node-chrome-debug
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      HUB_HOST: hub
    ports:
      - "32773:5900"

  hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
```

command I use:

```
 docker-compose -f .\docker-compose.yml up -d
```

Source :

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium